# Стражи Линукс Си

Tags: linux, c

Вот есть у меня код под Линукс, который должен следить за изменениями директорий или файлов. Это называется наблюдением (стражем). По этому коду у меня возникает два вопроса

1) Как выйти из программы? Здесь мы используем бесконечный цикл

```
while(1)
```

при этом у пользователя нет возможности завершить процесс. Есть только CTRL+C, но при этом текст из буфера не помещается в лог. Поэтому я дописал функцию

```
fflush(fp_log);
```

которая проталкивает текст из буфера в файл. Но короче говоря, это некрасиво. Как обеспечить выход из цикла? Я пробовал getch или getchar но у меня выходят ошибки.

2) Когда я создаю директорию или изменяю файл, то сообщение выводится в терминал, но когда удаляю файл или папку, или переименовываю, не выводится. Как сделать, чтобы выводилось? Добавить другую маску? Какую?

```
   /* Inotify используется для наблюдения за поддиректориями выбранной директории*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>


#define MAX_LEN 1024 /*длина пути для директории*/
#define MAX_EVENTS 1024 /*максимальное количество событий для обработки за один раз*/
#define LEN_NAME 16 /*предположим, что длина имени файла не превышает 16 байт*/
#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) ) /*размер структуры события*/
#define BUF_LEN     ( MAX_EVENTS * ( EVENT_SIZE + LEN_NAME )) /*буфер для хранения данных события*/


/* Файл журнала*/
FILE *fp_log;


/* Добавим наблюдения inotify для поддиректорий сразу после добавления корневой директории */

void add_watches(int fd, char *root)
{
    int wd;
    char *abs_dir;
    DIR *dp;

    dp = opendir(root);
    if (dp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the starting directory");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* добавление наблюдения для корневой директории */
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, root, IN_CREATE | IN_MODIFY | IN_DELETE); 
    if (wd == -1)
    {
        fprintf(fp_log,"Couldn't add watch to %s\n",root);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Watching:: %s\n",root);
    }
    closedir(dp);

}

/* Функция main*/
int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
    int length, i = 0;
    int fd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN], root[MAX_LEN];
    char s;


    /*Проверка наличия параметра командной строки*/
    switch(argc)
    {
        case 1: printf("No directory specified. Will monitor the entire filesystem...\n\n");
            strcpy(root,"/");
            break;

        case 2: strcpy(root,argv[1]);
            if(root[strlen(root)-1]!='/')
                strcat(root,"/");
            puts(root);

            break;

        default: printf("Ignoring all other arguments after the first\n");
    }


    /* Открытие файла журнала*/
    fp_log = fopen("asasas111.log","w+");
    if (fp_log == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening logger. All output will be redirected to the stdout\n");
    }

    fd = inotify_init();
    if ( fd < 0 ) {
        perror( "Couldn't initialize inotify");
    }

    /* обход поддиректорий первого уровня и добавление наблюдений */
    add_watches(fd,root);

    /* бесконечный цикл*/
    while(1)
    {
        i = 0;
        length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  

        if ( length < 0 ) {
            perror( "read" );
        }  

        /* чтентие событий*/
        while ( i < length ) {
            struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
            if ( event->len ) {
                if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE) {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                        fprintf(fp_log,"%d DIR::%s CREATED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        fflush(fp_log);
                        printf("%d DIR::%s CREATED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        }
                    else    {
                        fprintf(fp_log, "%d FILE::%s CREATED\n", event->wd, event->name);
                        fflush(fp_log);
                        printf("%d FILE::%s CREATED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        }
                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                        fprintf(fp_log,"%d DIR::%s MODIFIED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        fflush(fp_log);
                        printf("%d DIR::%s MODIFIED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        }
                    else    {
                        fprintf(fp_log,"%d FILE::%s MODIFIED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        printf("%d FILE::%s MODIFIED\n", event->wd,event->name );
                        }

                }

                if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE) {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                        fprintf(fp_log,"%d DIR::%s DELETED\n", event->wd,event->name );    
                        fflush(fp_log);   
                        printf("%d DIR::%s DELETED\n", event->wd,event->name ); 
                        } 
                    else    {
                        fprintf(fp_log,"%d FILE::%s DELETED\n", event->wd,event->name );     
                        fflush(fp_log); 
                        printf("%d FILE::%s DELETED\n", event->wd,event->name );  
                        }      
                }  

                i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;

            }
        }
    }
    /* освобождение ресурсов*/
    ( void ) close( fd );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Я пробовал getch или getchar но у меня выходят ошибки." что за ошибки? Вам бы по-хорошему ваш вопрос на два разделить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как выйти из программы?

Так тем же CTRL+C. Нужно просто ловить сигналы. Вот болванка для демонстрации подхода:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int terminate = 0;

static void signal_handler(int signo)
{
    switch (signo)
    {
        case SIGINT:
        case SIGTERM:
        case SIGTSTP:
            /* не помешает проверить: */
            if (!terminate)
            {
                terminate = 1;
                /* завершаем начатое и выходим: */
                printf("Got signal %u, bye!\n", signo);
                /*
                 *  fclose(fp_log);
                 *  close(fd);
                 *  и т.д.
                 */
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* Ctrl+C: */
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    /* Ctrl+Z, если надо: */
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);

    while (1)
    {
        if (!terminate)
        {
            /* что-то делаем: */
            puts("do something...");
            /* просто для имитации деятельности: */
            sleep(10);
        }
    }
    /*
     * а вот сюда мы никогда попасть не должны, но на всякий случай
     * вернём ошибку для индикации этого вопиющего недоразумения:
     */
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для корректного завершения програмы можно предложить пару вариантов.

1 вариант - создать именованый канал и в программе переодически опрашивать его, и когда нужно завершить программу в канал записывается ключевое слово и программа завершается.

2 вариант - в программе сделать функции обработчик сигналов и посылать эти сигналы в программу.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, из цикла тоже можно выйти через `break`. Хотя сам и не использовал - не приходилось. А дальше после цикла выходить из программы, предварительно записав логи и закрыв их.